# Django filter for result from checkbox form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm begginer of django and i try to implement search engine to look for recipes that contains selected ingredients.
I want to do form with all ingredients_type from my Model and user can select up to 3 of them (checkbox prefered). Then i want to filter recepe that contains them.
I was looking for generic form but never get right result.

Right now i have only a scratch and Im looking for any advice

model.py

```
class IngredientsType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```

search.html

```
{% for ingredients in ingredients_type %}
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ingredients.type}}">
    <label for="{{ingredients.type}}">{{ingredients.type}}</label>
{% endfor %}
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <button type="submit" name="save" value="save">szukaj</button>
</form>
```

Do i have to create custom form or there is good way to use some of generic form?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are on the right path, but there are some mistakes in your code.

**search.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for ingredients in ingredients_type %}
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ingredients.type}}" value="1">
        <label for="{{ingredients.type}}">{{ingredients.type}}</label>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" name="save" value="save">szukaj</button>
</form>
```

**model.py**

You might want to use [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) to represent to relation between the ingredient types and the recipes.

**views.py**

Make sure you have the `POST` handling method to work with your filter query. This should get data from the form.